# WxPython Loading Text

Tags: wxpython

So I was wondering if any one knew how to load text from a text file onto a frame.
My application Loads a Drum Notation and a Drum sound file that matches the Notation, and it loads these together. Now I need it to load some text to explain the Notation, and it should load the text together with the image and sound file.

```
def loadImage(self, event):
        self.image_file = self.images.next()
        print(self.image_file)
        image_file = os.path.join(IMAGE_DIR, self.image_file)
        img = wx.Image(image_file, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
        width = img.GetWidth()
        height = img.GetHeight()
        self.imageCtrl.SetBitmap(wx.BitmapFromImage(img))
```

This is the code that loads the image. You can also cycle back through each image and sound file as well.

Anyway, does anyone have a way to add to the code to load the text?

```
def loadImage(self, event):
self.image_file = self.images.next()
print(self.image_file)
image_file = os.path.join(IMAGE_DIR, self.image_file)
img = wx.Image(image_file, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
width = img.GetWidth()
height = img.GetHeight()
self.imageCtrl.SetBitmap(wx.BitmapFromImage(img))



def previousPicture(self, event):
    self.image_file = self.images.prev() 
    print(self.image_file)
    image_file = os.path.join(IMAGE_DIR, self.image_file)
    img = wx.Image(image_file, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
    img = img.Scale(680,143)
    self.imageCtrl.SetBitmap(wx.BitmapFromImage(img))

 def onPlaySound (self, event):
    sound_file, ext = os.path.splitext(self.image_file)
    sound_file = os.path.join(SOUND_DIR, sound_file + '.wav')
    print(sound_file)
    sound = wx.Sound(sound_file)
    sound.Play(wx.SOUND_ASYNC)

class DIter:
#"Iterable with next and previous"
 def __init__(self, ItemList):
    #"Creator"
    self.ItemList = ItemList
    self.Index = -1
    self.ListEnd = len(ItemList)

 def next(self):
     # """ Return the next item """
    self.Index += 1
    self.Index %= self.ListEnd # or to avoid wrapping self.Index = min([self.Index,   self.ListEnd-1])
    return self.ItemList[self.Index]

 def prev(self):
      #""" Return the previous item """
    self.Index -= 1
    if self.Index < 0:
        self.Index = self.ListEnd-1 # or to avoid wrapping self.Index = 0
    return self.ItemList[self.Index]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a wx.TextCtrl, probably with the wx.TE_MULTILINE flag and update it with the text. You would just read the text into a variable and then set your TextCtrl's value via its SetValue() method.

There are examples in the wxPython demo that can be downloaded from the wxPython website.

Here's an example that sort of works:

```
    import glob
import wx

########################################################################
class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.textFiles = glob.glob(r'C:\Users\mdriscoll\Documents\wx_testing\*.txt')
        self.currentFile = -1
        self.totalFiles = len(self.textFiles)

        mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        btnSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        self.txt = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        prevBtn = wx.Button(self, label="Prev")
        prevBtn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onPrev)
        nextBtn = wx.Button(self, label="Next")
        nextBtn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onNext)

        btnSizer.Add(prevBtn, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
        btnSizer.Add(nextBtn, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
        mainSizer.Add(self.txt, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        mainSizer.Add(btnSizer)

        self.SetSizer(mainSizer)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onPrev(self, event):
        """"""
        print self.currentFile
        if self.currentFile != -1:
            if self.currentFile == self.totalFiles:
                # need to subtract one to get the last element in the list
                self.currentFile -= 1
                fpath = self.textFiles[self.currentFile]
            else:
                fpath = self.textFiles[self.currentFile]

            # read file
            with open(fpath) as fh:
                data = fh.read()

            self.txt.SetValue(data)
            self.currentFile -= 1
        else:
            return

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onNext(self, event):
        """"""
        print self.currentFile
        if self.currentFile == -1:
            self.currentFile += 1

        if self.currentFile != self.totalFiles:
            fpath = self.textFiles[self.currentFile]
            # read file
            with open(fpath) as fh:
                data = fh.read()

            self.txt.SetValue(data)
            self.currentFile += 1
        else:
            return



########################################################################
class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="File reader")
        panel = MainPanel(self)
        self.Show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

It should give you the general idea anyway

Comment: To load the text from the text file on the the wx.TextCtrl should I just put it in the def LoadImage where it loads the images. The text should load together with the notation to explain it, If I'm getting my point across correctly.

Comment: Yeah, that would be fine. If the LoadImage call takes a long time, then you might end up needing to put the loading stuff into a thread.

Comment: Could you by any chance give me an example of how I'd go about doing this? Sorry to ask, newbie. This is how I thought it would be set out.self.text_file = self.text.next()
    text_file = os.path.join(TEXT_DIR, self.text_file)
    txt=wx.TextCtrl(text_file)
    self.textCtrl(self.panel)
I dont see anything in the demos that I can work with.

Comment: Cheers Mike! You really are the King of Wxpython haha! This works perfectly. One question. Anyway to change the font and size of the text in the box?
edit: Never mind, changed it to this self.txt.SetFont(wx.Font(14, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL, 0, u'Consolas'))

Comment: Hey Mike, could you have a look at the Previous function that you posted. It doesn't seem to work properly. Can't the text be loaded through the "class DIter" that I posted, so they are loaded in the same way that the images and sound files are loaded?

Comment: Yeah, I know it's not working quite right. It's just a quick script I threw together. I think if you print what number it's currently on, you'll see that there needs to be some more logic built in to prevent it from displaying the same file twice because basically it's adding 1 and you end up with 2 which is outside the list range. So when you hit previous, it goes back to 1 and shows the same file again. You should be able to adapt my code to iterate using your class.

Comment: Yeah, turns out I just needed something like this self.txt.LoadFile(os.path.join(TEXT_DIR, self.text.next())) so that it uses the iterate class that I created. I just couldn't get my head around to actually displaying it!